# Delete an inner node but not the value in xml with XDocument library in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
  <body>
    <p><span class="screenitems">Add</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I Want it to delete `<span>` node but the `Add` to exist, so it looks as follows at the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Add</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a good/simple way to do this?

Comment: it might be best to use html agility pack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ReplaceWith`, e.g.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
XElement span = doc.Descendants("p").First().Elements("span").FirstOrDefault(s => (string)s.Attribute("class") == "screenitems");
if (span != null) 
{
  span.ReplaceWith(span.Nodes());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remark: Your XML looks like HTML-Code. HTML is not always a valid XML (see the BR-Tag: `<br>`). That might cause exceptions - so you either should be very sure that your HTML is a valid XML (then you can use `XDocument`) or you should use `Regex.Replace()`

```
Regex spanRegex = new Regex(@"<span[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)</span[^>]*>");
spanRegex.Replace(input, match => { return match.Groups[1].ToString(); });
```

(see http://regexr.com/3cjuq)

Comment: it should always be xml specific :D but thanks for the regex.