# Encoding problems with XDocument XElement when using ReplaceWith method

Tags: c#, html, regex, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
var x = doc.Descendants("span");

XElement xelm = x.FirstOrDefault(xm => xm.Attribute("class").Value=="screenitems");

Regex rgx = new Regex("^<span class=\"screenitems\">(.*)</span>$");
Match mtc = rgx.Match(xelm.Value);
if (mtc.Success)
{
    xelm.ReplaceWith(mtc.Groups[1].Value);
}
doc.Save(file);
```

When I get a match and replace the content of the XML file loaded into variable `doc` using the `ReplaceWith` method for the `XElement` variable `xelm`, the content of the XML file is getting encoded, so instead of having a tag like `<p>` I get `&lt;p&gt`.

So How can I prevent that it encodes into html but actually replaces with the matched regex expression?

I have looked at some of the solutions here, like using `XElement.Parse` method or `HTTPUtility.HtmlDecode`, but I couldn't get it to work. It still encodes like html.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output of what you are attempting to achieve?  On the face of it, what you are doing seems strange and ill-advised.  `XElement` already parses the document for you, so it's wildly unusual to then be using `Regex` to parse it.  Whatever you're trying to do, there's got to be a better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete an inner node but not the value in xml with XDocument library in C# .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874027/delete-an-inner-node-but-not-the-value-in-xml-with-xdocument-library-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could try and parse your RegEx match into `XElement`s to solve the problem, I think you're going about this the wrong way.

As I understand it, your requirement is to replace a `span` element with the `screenItems` class with its contents. Rather than doing this using a combination of LINQ to XML and RegEx, you should stick to LINQ to XML.

Find all your `span` elements with the `screenItems` class:

```
var spans = doc.Descendants("span")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("class") == "screenItems")
    .ToList();
```

Then replace each of these with their own content:

```
foreach (var span in spans)
{
    span.ReplaceWith(span.Nodes());
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9H3fma) for a working example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer. I will try to see if it works. Thanks.