# Parse XML with XDocument using C#

Tags: c#, html, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p><p>
           <span class="screenitems">
               Close 
               <MCap:variable name="1052.zartzut"></MCap:variable> 
               without prompting if you launch a non-
               <MCap:variable name="zirtZat"></MCap:variable>
               measurement module. (You will be prompted to save any unsaved data.)
               <span lol="scs">dsfsfs</span>
            </span>
        </p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to only delete `<span class="screenitems">` and the corresponding end tag `</span>`, so it should after parsing look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p><p>

               Close 
               <MCap:variable name="1052.zartzut"></MCap:variable> 
               without prompting if you launch a non-
               <MCap:variable name="zirtZat"></MCap:variable>
               measurement module. (You will be prompted to save any unsaved data.)
               <span lol="scs">dsfsfs</span>

        </p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

`<span class="screenitems">`  is the only unique tag so in between this and `<html>`, you can have everything. Can you help me with this issue using `XDocument` methods in `C#` ?

Comment: Generally `XDocument` as well as any other xml parser is not a best tool to parse html. The reason of it is the fact that valid html code not necessary will be valid xml. You'd better use some html parser, for example, html agility pack.

Comment: How is this different to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001487/encoding-problems-with-xdocument-xelement-when-using-replacewith-method/35009493#35009493)?  You should just update that question rather than starting another.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev This will be used in another program, which requires it to be a valid XML file.

Comment: @CharlesMager I havent been aware of the different cases, and I already accepted the answer. Thats why.

Comment: I don't follow.  There is no accepted answer to your previous question, and no response from you to questions in comments. I added an answer there. If I was to answer this question I would put the same answer.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You now have *three* questions asking the same thing. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874027/delete-an-inner-node-but-not-the-value-in-xml-with-xdocument-library-in-c-sharp) has the correct answer and the same answer applies to this question.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Comment: This is html - XML parser are not good choise for parse files like this. I prefer `HTMLAgilePack` to parse html

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{        
string html = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p><p>
           <span class=""screenitems"">
               Close 
               <MCap:variable name=""1052.zartzut""></MCap:variable> 
               without prompting if you launch a non-
               <MCap:variable name=""zirtZat""></MCap:variable>
               measurement module. (You will be prompted to save any unsaved data.)
               <span lol=""scs"">dsfsfs</span>
            </span>
        </p></p>
    </body>
</html>";

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var spanNode = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "span" && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "screenitems").First();

        var parent = spanNode.ParentNode;

        parent.RemoveChild(spanNode, true);

        Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
}
```

You should use Html parser, here how you can do it with Html Agility Pack. The trick here is done by `parent.RemoveChild(Node, keepGrandChilds);`